# How to Trigger Multibranch Jobs from Bitbucket Cloud?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Following and implementing all the steps in [How to Trigger Multibranch Jobs from Bitbucket Cloud?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000051132), I still can't trigger a branch build from a Bitbucket push event.

1. I wrote a Jenkinsfile in one of my repositories, in a specific branch named `feature/add-jenkinsfile`.
2. I created a Multi-branch job (through Jenkin's Blue Ocean UI) and filled all the correct credentials and scanning in the Bitbucket source section.
3. I created a webhook in the Bitbucket's repository to `http://<jenkins>/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify`, triggered by push events.

Initial scanning had detected my `feature/add-jenkinsfile` branch and build it to success, but push commits to the branch are not triggering such build. Bitbucket is sending webhooks to the above URL and is getting HTTP 200 response, so the problem relies in Jenkins.

What Jenkins configuration am I missing to enable this basic requirement?

Comment: check in the Jenkins log if he knows how to process the webhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the removal of pre-installed BitBucket plugin that consumed the BitBucket push without handling it (hence the HTTP 200 response status to BitBucket Cloud), thanks to [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-push-and-pull-request-plugin/issues/19#issuecomment-488609438) issue comment.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue you've described and I tried the solution by removing the BitBucket plugin but the build is still not triggering for me. Do I need to add some other plugin in BitBucket or Jenkins to make this work?

Comment: This was a while back, but it was definitely caused by a plugin. If I were you I would focus on finding that plugin that consumes the webhook call, because that was the solution to my issue.

Comment: The issue linked to in the answer is relevant for the "Bitbucket Push and Pull Request" plugin which uses the same webhook endpoint as the "Bitbucket" plugin and therefore can't work together. 

The "Bitbucket Branch Source" plugin relevant to the original question uses a different endpoint so it doesn't conflict with the "Bitbucket" plugin. The problem must have been elsewhere.